# how to load multiple samples in mne from a txt/csv file?

Tags: eeg

I have an EEG csv data set of 268 samples. In every sample, there's data for 6 EEG channels, and every channel has 896 data points (256 Hz, 3.5 s).
At first, I interpolated and filtered the data one by one.

```
ch_names = ['A1', 'A2', 'F3', 'P3', 'F4', 'P4'] # channel names   
sfreq = 256 # sampling frequency, in hertz  
ch_type = ['eeg']*6
info = mne.create_info(ch_names, sfreq, ch_type) 
raw_files = []
for j in range(0,268):
    raw_files.append(mne.io.RawArray(samples[j], info)) 
raw = raw_files[0]

raw = raw.set_montage(mont1020_new)
updated_mont = raw.get_montage()
```

Here, samples is a numpy array of [268][6][896] size.

Now I'm keen to rereference the signals, and to find events, but couldn't do that as I couldn't load all the samples to mne. How to find events and epochs in this case?

Comment: I believe that's a programming question, I suggest you ask at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I've solved this issue, could I post the answer  here or in stack overflow?